# Call a url that writes to a file on a server (free)

Tags: python, html, url

What I'm asking may sound strange, but I really need it..

What I need is a url that I can setup (like a free server with php support, but something reliable) and call that url from python with the arguments I need and it would write the values to a file.

I don't know if what I really need is a server with php (I hope not).

Is there anyway of doing it with google docs? are there any other services you guys came across that where any good?

Ps. I need this for a program that shows the user some thumbnails and lets the user tell what kind of pic it is ( it's done by clicking a button wich I hope will call the URL I'm asking for with the arguments)

Clear enough?

Ps. Not like captcha. I just need to call for example http:/aaa.a/file.xxx?id=1&tag=funny

So that I present my user with the images, and as they click to choose the apropriate tag, that url writes it to file (a file I can later have acces to)

Comment: Kind of like captcha or image-based authentication?

Comment: This sort of thing is often done with a database, rather than writing directly to a file. You could look at Google Appengine, which lets you create web apps for free in Python or Java. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a script that you can execute on the server. This can be written in any language you want. Python works fine. Unless loads of people call the URL at once you can use CGI (it's a bit slow when using Python).